# Erro no retorno de condição

Tags: c, condição

mesmo após digitar um valor negativo, o else nao retorna nada ;(

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    //variaveis
    int dia, mes, ano;

    //inicio
    printf("\ndigite o dia: ");
    scanf("%d", &dia);

    printf("\ndigite o mes: ");
    scanf("%d", &mes);

    printf("\ndigite o ano: ");
    scanf("%d", &ano);

    if(dia>0 == mes>0 == ano>0)
    if(mes>=1 == mes <=12)
    if(dia>=1 == dia<=30)
    if(ano>=1)
    {
        printf("\nEssa data eh valida!");
    }

    else
    {   
        printf("\nEssa data nao eh valida!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá!!
Sugiro que enquanto aprende a linguagem siga atentamente a forma mas simples, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    //variaveis
    int dia, mes, ano;

    //inicio
    printf("\ndigite o dia: ");
    scanf("%d", &dia);

    printf("\ndigite o mes: ");
    scanf("%d", &mes);

    printf("\ndigite o ano: ");
    scanf("%d", &ano);

    if(mes>=1 && mes <=12)
    {
        if(dia>=1 && dia<=30)
        {
            if(ano>=1)
            {
                printf("\nEssa data eh valida!");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nEssa data nao eh valida!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEssa data nao eh valida!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nEssa data nao eh valida!");
    }   
}
```

Tratando corretamente cada condição podemos controlar melhor o nosso código, veja que é o mesmo código, as condições continuam as mesmas mas agora funciona, trata-se apenas da identação. Como você está em processo de treinamento(coloquemos assim) com [estruturas condicionais básicas](https://br.ccm.net/faq/10200-linguagem-c-estruturas-condicionais), siga **entendendo o funcionamento delas e futuramente lide com a simplificação do código**.

Answer (score 0):

A condição correta é a seguinte:

```
if (mes >= 1 && mes <= 12 && dia >= 1 && dia <= 31 && ano >= 1) {
    printf("\nEssa data eh valida!");
} else {
    printf("\nEssa data nao eh valida!");
}
```

Não confunda o operador `&&` com `==`, pois são muito diferentes tanto no comportamento quanto conceitualmente.

A condições `dia>0`, `mes>0` e `ano>0` são redundantes frente as demais restrições que já existem, e por isso, são desnecessárias.

Ah, e isso é claro, ainda desconsidera o fato de que nem todos os meses tem um dia 31 e que fevereiro pode ter 28 ou 29 dias. Para isso, algumas condições mais complexas seriam necessárias, mas como você está apenas começando, vamos ficar com esse caso mais simples de que todos os meses podem ter 31 dias. Mas se você quiser realmente saber, para lidar com esses casos (considerando que o calendário seja sempre o gregoriano), a condição seria a seguinte:

```
if (dia >= 1 && dia <= 31 && mes >= 1 && mes <= 12 && ano >= 1 && (dia <= 28 || mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes == 8 || mes == 10 || mes == 12 || (dia <= 30 && mes != 2) || (dia == 29 && ano % 4 == 0 && (ano % 100 != 0 || ano % 400 == 0)))) {
```

O uso de `if`s encadeados não ocorre da forma como você imaginava. Se não sabe ainda como funciona o `if` sem o `{` e o `}` que a ele se seguem, então sempre use o `{` e o `}` nele. Somente use o `if` sem o `{` e o `}` quando já tiver certeza de como funciona e já souber avaliar quando isso é ou não uma boa ideia (e na maioria das vezes, não colocar o `{` e o `}` no `if` não é uma boa ideia).